# how do i filter by date using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I need to filter my spreadsheet based on today's date.
this is the code I used:

```
function myFunction() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("19nlPw9jF8FCFwY-qYwdBILoGDazrH12c8BgYfhwWSKA");
  var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName("All Joiners");
  var Jun = SS.getSheetByName("01 Jun");
  var data = Sheet.getRange(2, 1,Sheet.getLastRow(),Sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.FilterCriteriaBuilder.whenDateEqualTo(new Date(Jun.getRange("A1")))
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);

}
```

Comment: Does `new Date()` work for you?

Comment: Can you clarify what's the value in cell `A1`? Also, do you want the date to be exactly equal or just to be the same day?

Comment: The value in cell A1 can be any date. most commonly today's date to filter out data for today.

Comment: no new Date( ) doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

A few things -

- Your code retrieves the **range** of cell A1 on Jun - You also need
  to get the **value**.
- FilterCriteriaBuilder is not a  function and
  should be newFilterCriteria().
- spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() should
  be SS.getActiveSheet since you declared it as SS

Original Code:

```
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.FilterCriteriaBuilder.whenDateEqualTo(new Date(Jun.getRange("A1"))).build(); 
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
```

Should be:

```
let criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateEqualTo(new Date(Jun.getRange("A1").getValue())).build();    
SS.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
```

Also, side note - you declared Sheet but didn't use it.  If your intention was to update the column filter on that specific sheet and not the currently active sheet, then instead of SS.getActiveSheet(), it should be:

```
Sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
```

If your sheet doesn't currently have a filter, you have to create it. In order to do that, retrieve the `Range` you want to apply the filter to and then call [Range.createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createFilter()). So that line would be something like (`Range` being your desired range):

```
Range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
```

Also, if your `A1` cell is a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (and not a string formatted like a Date) there's no need to use `new Date()` when setting the criteria:

```
const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateEqualTo(Jun.getRange("A1").getValue()).build();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, upon trying this I get an error message that reads - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setColumnFilterCriteria' of null
myFunction"

Comment: @AbhijithP That means you currently don't have a filter in your sheet. In order to create it, retrieve the `Range` you want to apply the filter to and then call [Range.createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createFilter()). So the full line would be `Range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);`. Also, if your `A1` cell is a `Date` (and not a string formatted like a Date) there's no need to use `new Date()` when setting the criteria: `whenDateEqualTo(Jun.getRange("A1").getValue())`.